# How to maintain a shared data between two nodes in a cluster using hazelcast

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast

I have two nodes in a cluster. I want to pass on a data / variable to another node if a node shuts down in a cluster. How can I maintain this shared data using Hazelcast and Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for Hazelcast, you don't need to do anything.

The default is that a data record written in an [IMap](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html) is stored on two nodes in the cluster but can be accessed from anywhere in the cluster.

If you want to know when a node joins or leaves the cluster, use a [MembershipListener](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MembershipListener.html)